# "NoSuchMethodError" caused by FluentWait.until on Appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I'm starting to automate one app (on Android and iOS). The idea is to make the Page Objects reusable, so i'm using @AndroidFindBy and @iOSFindBy methods to get the elements on the app.

I have developed some Page Objects for the app and i'm starting to write a few tests. But the problem is that every time that i have to use a MobileElement, IntelliJ is throwing me a NoSuchMethodError.
It is only happening when the Element is instanciated and inicialized using those @FindBy methods. If I hardcode the finding of the element inside of a method, for example, it works properly.

**This does not work**

```
import io.appium.java_client.MobileDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.SelendroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.iOSFindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class ActivityMain {

   private final MobileDriver driver;
   private WebDriverWait wait;

   //@iOSFindBy(id = "")
   @SelendroidFindBy(id = "com.testapp.uzapp:id/qrButton")
   public MobileElement qrButton;


   public ActivityMain(MobileDriver driver) {
      this.driver = driver;
      wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
      PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
   }

   public ActivityQRScan goToQRScan() {              
      qrButton.click();
      return new ActivityQRScan(this.driver);
   }
}
```

But

**This Works Nice**

```
package com.userzoom.appium.pageobjects;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.SelendroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.iOSFindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class ActivityMain {

   private final MobileDriver driver;
   private WebDriverWait wait;

   //@iOSFindBy(id = "")
   @SelendroidFindBy(id = "com.testapp.uzapp:id/qrButton")
   public MobileElement qrButton;

   public ActivityMain(MobileDriver driver) {
      this.driver = driver;
      wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
      PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
   }

   public ActivityQRScan goToQRScan() {           
      driver.findElement(By.id("com.userzoom.uzapp:id/qrButton")).click();

      /* This Works too
      WebElement qrButton = driver.findElement(By.id("com.userzoom.uzapp:id/qrButton"));*/
      return new ActivityQRScan(this.driver);
   }
}
```

The error that is giving me:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;

at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.waitFor(AppiumElementLocator.java:88)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:103)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfASingleElement.intercept(InterceptorOfASingleElement.java:57)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c0b591f0.click(<generated>)
at com.userzoom.appium.pageobjects.ActivityMain.goToQRScan(ActivityMain.java:57)
at com.userzoom.appium.testcases.android.QR.QR001.QR001(QR001.java:54)
```

On the maven configuration pom, i have guava at version 21 and selenium at version 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved randomly after changing the version of selenium-server at pom to 3.0.1...
3.5.2 was giving me even NullPointerExceptions for elements that were obviously present

Answer (score 2):

Using the `FindBy` annotations, the way you should access the elements is:

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "com.testapp.uzapp:id/qrButton")
@iOSFindBy(id = "com.testapp.uzapp:id/qrButton")
@SelendroidFindBy(id = "com.testapp.uzapp:id/qrButton")
public MobileElement qrButton;
```

shall be further accessed as :

```
public ActivityQRScan goToQRScan(){
    qrButton.click(); // no more driver.findElement
}
```

[Appium's unit test](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/java/junit/src/test/java/com/saucelabs/appium/page_object/widgets/RottenTomatoes.java#L38) very well justifies the usage of the annotations.

---

***Edit***:

Note for Android if you're testing for multiple android SDK versions:

> Selendroid is currently bundled into the Appium package in order to
>   provide support for Android versions 2.3 through 4.1(API 10 to 19). Appium
>   automatically switches to Selendroid when users want to run tests for
>   these Android versions.

And probably the device you're testing on(iOS), doesn't support the Selendroid framework.

On when to use Selendroid or Appium, [here](https://saucelabs.com/blog/selendroid-vs-appium-which-to-choose-for-your-mobile-app-testing) is a good read.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time seeing how this differs from what the OP is doing in the example that doesn't work?

Comment: @mrfreester there are multiple ways of accessing WebElement. OP is trying to access the same element implementing multiple ways at the same time.

Comment: in the example given that doesn't work, I don't see any instance of `driver.findElement`. I only see both in the example that does work, where it seems the annotation was just left in there but isn't being used as OP is using `driver.findElement` instead. If I understand correctly, the question is why does the error happen when using the annotation version, like in your answer.

Comment: @mrfreester Actually, you're correct. The difference was of Selendroid tried on an iOS device which is not supported. Update the answer.

Comment: I'm not testing in iOS! D: The Devices where i'm running the test are Android (7.0 and 8.0).
The problem is that using annotations, the tests fail and give me that error, but the elements can be found using the driver.findElement, passing the same id than in the annotations....

Comment: @Farmijo same implies for the android version you're testing as mentioned in the highlighted portion in the answer.

Comment: @Farmijo In your solution you're trying to access and Android element using Selendroid annotation. Which is supported for specific version of SDK. And the framework instrumentation of Appium takes care of injecting specific one according to the version

Comment: @nullpointer Using AndroidFindBy annotation i'm receiving the same error